# How to send Spring Bean serialized as the body of a REST call using Web Client in a Java Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to make a REST call at regular intervals with same parameters every time, drawn from application properties. To avoid creating the request object every time, I want to use a Configuration Bean as request body which will be serialized to JSON.

The configuration bean looks like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprefix")
@Configuration("configname")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ConfigDetails {

    private String c1;

    private String c2;

    private String c3;
}
```

And I inject this bean into the class calling the REST API with `@Autowired` annotation. On making the REST call, during serialization I get the following error:

```
 No serializer found for class org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.ril.scm.node.data.PromiseEngineLoginDetails$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cad0a6e6["$$beanFactory"]->org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory["beanExpressionResolver"])
```

I am using a WebClient to make the call like below:

```
webClient.post().body(Mono.just(configDetails), ConfigDetails.class)....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I tried creating a static non-bean copy of the Configuration Bean inside the class, copied the field value and used that static instance instead.

This worked but I am not sure if this can be considered a solution or just a hack! The downside I can see is someone can forget to edit the `init()` method at times there is a need to add a property.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprefix")
@Configuration("configname")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ConfigDetails {

    private String c1;

    private String c2;

    private String c3;

    private static ConfigDetails staticConfigDetails;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        staticConfigDetails = new ConfigDetails();
        staticConfigDetails.setC1(this.c1);
        ...
        //set other properties
        ....
        
    }

    public static ConfigDetails getInstance(){
        return staticConfigDetails;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing here may seem hacky but it addresses the underlying issue correctly. When you `@Autowire`, it's a spring bean and not a POJO. So calling `Mono.just(configDetails, ConfigDetails.class)` throws an error because the object passed for serialization is a bean. With this approach, you're actually passing a POJO for serialization and hence, it works. Only suggestion would be to get rid of `static` modifiers - since it's a bean, you can simply autowire and call the method - `Mono.just(configDetails.getInstance(), ConfigDetails.class)`.